# a Windows version 10.0.18362-based image is incompatible with a 10.0.14393 host

Tags: docker, window

Created one docker file for simple hello world (.net application ).image and container is running fine. I have pushed this image to docker hub and want to pull that image from windows 2016 server ( GCP Environment ) but i am getting below error.
error is Compatible issue, i have no idea with windows os can anyone help me on this issue.

i have to dockerization .net application (GUI) on window server

Error 
a Windows version 10.0.18362-based image is incompatible with a 10.0.14393 host

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/version-compatibility

Answer (score 1):

Check the supported OS version for each docker image at [Nano Server image page](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-nanoserver) or [here (Server Core image page](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-servercore).